# string "cross correlation" in matlab

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation

Assume that I have 2 strings of characters:

```
AACCCGGAAATTTGGAATTTTCCCCAAATACG

CGATGATCGATGAATTTTAGCGGATACGATTC
```

I want to find by how much I should move the second string such that it matches the first one the most.

There are 2 cases. The first one is that we assume that the string are wrapped around, and the second one is that we don't.

Is there a matlab function that does returns either a N array or 2N+1 array of values for how much the shifted string 2 correlates with string 1?

If not, is there a faster/simpler method than something like

```
result = zeroes(length, 1)
for i = 0:length-1
    result(i+1) = sum (str1 == circshift(str2, i));
end
```

Comment: You might like to take a look at Bioinformatics Toolbox, which contains implementations of Smith-Waterman and Needleman-Wunsch alignment algorithms.

Answer (score 5):

You can convert each char into a binary column of size 4:

```
A -> [1;0;0;0]
C -> [0;1;0;0]
G -> [0;0;1;0]
T -> [0;0;0;1]
```

As a result a string of length `n` becomes a binary matrix of size `4`-by-`n`.

You can now cross-correlate (along X axis only) the two `n`-by-4 and `m`-by-4 to get your result.

Comment: Why `4`-by-`n` matrix? Isn't it simpler to convert the string to ASCII codes with `double(String)` and work with `1`-by-`n` (or `n`-by-`1`, if you like) vector?

Comment: @anandr - good question. If you convert the string to numeric (by ascii or any other conversion) you will have **positive** correlation between the numeric values of one character and a *different* one. By converting to binary vectors the correlation between two vectors of different chars is **zero**.

Comment: Good point. +1 for solving one of my old problems in more efficient way :o)

Comment: Fascinating. The conversion would be done through a for loop, I'd imagine?

Comment: @useretothepowerof2pi not at all! you can use look-up-table and vectorize this operation quite easily.

Answer (score 4):

With a hat tip to [John d'Errico](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22858-circulant-matrix/content/circulant.m):

```
str1 = 'CGATGATCGATGAATTTTAGCGGATACGATTC';
str2 = 'AACCCGGAAATTTGGAATTTTCCCCAAATACG';

% the circulant matrix
n = length(str2);
C = str2( mod(bsxfun(@plus,(0:n-1)',0:n-1),n)+1 ); %//'

% Find the maximum number of matching characters, and the amount 
% by which to shift the string to achieve this result
[score, shift] = max( sum(bsxfun(@eq, str1, C), 2) );
```

Faster yes, simpler...well, I'll leave that up to you to decide :)

Note that this method trades memory for speed. That is, it creates the matrix of *all* possible shifts in memory (efficiently), and compares the string to all rows of this matrix. That matrix will contain `N²` elements, so if `N` becomes large, it's better to use the loop (or Shai's method).

Comment: But this will not give me an array of how much they match, will it?

Comment: "I want to find by how much I should move the second string such that it matches the first one the most." That's what I implemented...

Comment: But just remove the `max(...)` and you'll get the full array for *all* shifts.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis sometimes you just can't make them happy... +1 for the nice solution (and patience)

Comment: Indeed, some people are just naturally unhappy. Hmm, n won't be too large, I think. So this solution will work.